# Minimize code changes when editing the constructor of a data type

Tags: haskell

I have a data type to keep track of state. Let's say it looks like this:

```
data State = State String String Int
```

Several functions take a `State` and return a new one. For example:

```
convert :: State -> Int -> State
convert (State a b c) 0 = State "new" b c
convert (State a b c) 1 = State a "new" c
convert (State a b c) 2 = State a b 0
```

(1) When I edit the `State` data type (to hold an additional `Int`, for instance) I need to edit the pattern-matching in all functions. Is it better to use record syntax in this case?

```
data State = State { a :: String, b :: String, c :: Int }

convert :: State -> Int -> State
convert state 0 = State "new" (b state) (c state)
convert state 1 = State (a state) "new" (c state)
convert state 2 = State (a state) (b state) 0
```

Now I don't have to edit the pattern-matching when changing the data type `State`. The construcor calls on the right hand side suffer from the same problem though. Is there a way around this? I could define some functions to create `State`s (only those needed be manipulated when the `State` constructor changes).

(2) I guess there are other ways of handling this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use record update syntax:

```
convert state 0 = state { a = "new" }
convert state 1 = state { b = "new" }
convert state 2 = state { c = 0 }
```

Or you could use lenses (in particular Edward's [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) library):

```
{-# LANGUAGE: TemplateHaskell #-}
import Control.Lens

data State = State
    { _a :: String
    , _b :: String
    , _c :: Int
    } deriving (Eq, Show, Read)
makeLenses ''State

convert :: Int -> State -> State
convert 0 = set a "new"
convert 1 = set b "new"
convert 2 = set c 0
-- Or using the infix version of set
-- convert 0 = a .~ "new"
-- convert 1 = b .~ "new"
-- convert 2 = c .~ 0
```

If you want to know more about the black magic that occurs in the lens library, there are many, many tutorials out there and the documentation is generally pretty good, but that is outside of the scope of this question